# how can i use array declared inside script tag in entire page

Tags: javascript, html

i declared newArrx array inside script tag and when i use it this error shown

```
newArrx is not defined
```

my HTML code

```
<div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <!-- ###### row number 4 ###### -->
                    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Function name" style="width:200px" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    <button onclick="newElement()" type="button" style="width:130px; margin-left:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Add function </button>

                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <!-- ###### row number 6 ###### -->
                    
                    <div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                      <select name="p[0]" style="width:100px; display:inline;" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected></option>
        
                         <%newArrx.forEach(function(item) {%>
                        <option><%= item %></option>
                      <%})%>
                      </select>
```

my javascript code (in the same page with html)

```
<script type="module">
          var newArrx = new Array;

        function newElement() {
          var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
          if (inputValue === '') {
            alert("You must write something!");
          } else {
            console.log(inputValue);

          }
          newArrx.push(inputValue);
          console.log(newArrx);
          console.log(newArrx.length);
          document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
          return newArrx;
        }

  </script>
```

the output :
newArrx is not defined

Comment: In you HTML code where is element with id `myInput`?

Comment: check the code i edited it

Comment: Try removing `type="module"` from your script, or directly add `newArrx` to the window via something like `globalThis.newArrx = new Array`.

Comment: thanks mr Ben but still same error

Answer (score 1):

`type="module"` is used to manage multiple js files. So in your code, you don't need to import or export any other js code, so just don't use `type="module"`.

I put your code in a separated js file and it worked fine, then put it back in the HTML file but I removed `type="module"` and it worked fine.

So you better use `type="module"` properly or just remove it if you don't need it.

you can learn more about `type=module` [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_modules.asp)

```html
 <div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <!-- ###### row number 4 ###### -->
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Function name" style="width:200px" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
        <button onclick="newElement()" type="button" style="width:130px; margin-left:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Add function </button>

      </div>
      
      <div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <!-- ###### row number 6 ###### -->
        
        <div class="row" style="width:458px; margin-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
          <select name="p[0]" style="width:100px; display:inline;" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected></option>

             <%newArrx.forEach(function(item) {%>
            <option><%= item %></option>
          <%})%>
          </select>

          <script>

            var newArrx = new Array;
  
          function newElement() {
            var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            if (inputValue === '') {
              alert("You must write something!");
            } else {
              console.log(inputValue);
  
            }
            newArrx.push(inputValue);
            console.log(newArrx);
            console.log(newArrx.length);
            document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
            return newArrx;
          }
  
    </script>
```